# Will there be an App-Indicators Repository in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, indicator

I heard that panel applets will be disabled in Ubuntu 11.04 and there will be indicators only. In Maverick we can right click and add panel applets and I use them a lot. So will there be a similar repository or some other way so that we can add new indicators? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any plans for collecting "cool little applets" in one place for 11.04.

If an application uses the indicator area it will either just use it or give you an option to use it in it's preferences.